# How to use yup with react hook form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, yup

I am trying to write error handling on react hook form with yup, but when I want to pass resolver as documentation says (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hookform/resolvers) I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> module.exports = require("@hookform/resolvers/yup");

My validation schema:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  person: Yup.string()
    .min(3, "To pole jest za krótkie")
    .max(30, "To pole jest za długie")
    .required("To pole jest wymagane"),
});
```

React hook form:

```
const {
    register,
    errors,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isSubmitting },
  } = useForm({ resolver: yupResolver(schema) });
```

Imports:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as Yup from "yup";
```

Npm version:

```
"react-hook-form": "^6.15.1",
"yup": "^0.28.3"
"@hookform/resolvers": "^1.3.4",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in `react-hook-form`.
https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/issues/107

The only fix as of today, if you use react-hook-form v6, is to downgrade `@hookform/resolvers` to `1.3.0`, or use a beta version `2.0.0-beta.3`. Newer versions support only react-hook-form v7.